# Excel VBA Runtime Error when deleting cells data

Tags: excel, vba

Let me preface this by saying I barely understand what I'm doing here and that I have zero coding experience short of making a few crappy HTML pages 20 years ago.

With alot of research and some help from communities such as these, I managed to put together an Excel VBA script to update the date, copy data when a column is updated to another excel sheet and, also, when certain conditions are met, copy the line to yet another sheet and delete the line after copying it on the original page.  We use it as an internal CRM at our small business and it mostly works for our purposes.

However, I was never able to get rid of the Runtime errors that we sometimes get when working with the file.  This creates issues with the users, not all very computer literate, as they sometimes hit debug instead of end and start typing in the VBA code by mistake, breaking the code and requiring me to go in and manually fix it.

I don't always get quality debug info from my users but the most common errors I personally see when troubleshooting is Runtime Error 424, when deleting data within a cell but not the whole row.

I assume this happens because it's not specified what happens when data is deleted in the code and it tries to keep running but I have no idea how to actually tell it to stop/fix it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the VBA code in our spreadsheet :

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 11
xTimeColumn = 12
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
    If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
            For Each xRg In xDPRg
                If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now
                End If
        Next
    End If

Dim a As Range
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
    End If
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Renewal" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Renewal" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

Here's the new version of the code that throws error 1004 after applying the corrections suggested below :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 11
xTimeColumn = 12
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
    If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now
        Else
            Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
            For Each xRg In xDPRg
                If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now
                End If
        Next
    End If

Dim a As Range
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
    End If
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Renewal" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(11), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If a.Value = "Renewal" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot see in your code a single cell deletion. What do you need from us regarding the posted code? It is, at least, strange, using 6 or 7 iteration for things which could be done in a single iteration. In the first iteration you placed `Next a` before `End If`. So, what kind of help do you need regarding the posted code? Like optimization, to make the code faster, it would be good to create Union ranges to be delete at once at the code end. Not knowing what you try accomplishing, I think that the `End If` after `Application.EnableEvents = False` should be at the code end.

Comment: What do you mean 'deleting data within a cell '?

Comment: As mentionned, we use this as a CRM so it's a table full of data (name, rep, date, product, dollar value, status of account, etc).  The script is built to take action when data is column 11 is updated to one of the choices in the dropdown menu we set up within the spreadsheet.  However, when someone deletes the data manually (they press delete) within a cell that already had data, it throws the Runtime error.  I hope that's a little clearer for you ?

Comment: So, do you want referring to cell contents clearing? If yes, the code throws an error because your code does not treat in any way the case of a Target empty cell. What do you like the code to do in such a case? To ignore the content clearing? To execute UnDo and warn the user? What do you like it to proceed? And what you try clarifying does not answer any of the questions I asked in my comment and no reference to my suggestions, too.

Comment: 1. (`If Not...`) The code will run even if there is no intersection. It should be `If Intersect(...) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. 2. (`Dim xCellColumn...`) This part is written as if the intersection will be only one cell e.g. `Target.Text` will not work on multiple cells. BTW get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line. 3. (`Dim a...`) `For Each a In...` indicates that there may be more cells but then you blow it by using `Target.Value` (instead of `a.Value`) which again will not work on multiple intersected cells. Please do clarify if both (2. and 3.) should run for multiple intersecting cells.

Comment: FaneDuru : I'm referring to when  a user clears data from a cell, yes.  We'd want the script to simply ignore the deletion when it happens and not do anything.

Comment: VBasic2008 : I've tried the changes as best as I could understand them.  It no longer throws an error when we clear the data in a cell so that's great!  However, I now get Runtime Error 1004 Intersect of object Golbal Failed when we choose one of the options that fire the second copy (and deletion) of the script (Closed Won, Closed Lost, Renewal).  The action still happens properly as far as I can tell but there must be something missing.  I'll post the updated code in my original post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really following all the logic, but something like this might be more manageable:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const COL_TARGET As Long = 11
    Const COL_NOW As Long = 12
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v, ws As Worksheet
    
    'any changes in Col 11 ?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, _
                  Me.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Columns(COL_TARGET))
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to handle
    
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = c.Value
        
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Cells(COL_NOW) = Now
            c.EntireRow.Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        Select Case v
            Case "Closed Won": Set ws = Sheet2
            Case "Closed Lost": Set ws = Sheet5
            Case "Renewal": Set ws = Sheet6
            Case Else: Set ws = Nothing
        End Select
        
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then 'made a match? Copy and delete
            c.EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            c.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    
    Next c
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, there appears to be steps missing from what we need to do with our data and I,m unsure how to adapt your script to ours, if required.  Here's what the code is supposed to do : 1) When column 11 is updated, update the date in column 12 for that row. 
2) Copy the whole row to a "log" sheet in the next available blank row when data in column 11 is updated 3) If data is updated to either "Closed Won", "Closed Lost" or "Renewed", copy the whole row to the corresponding Sheet on the first available blank row.  When 3) happens, delete the copied row in the "CRM" sheet

Comment: It doesn't do that?  The only part I couldn't follow was the Dependents part...

Comment: Actually scratch my last comment.  I didn't have the time to test it in excel yet, I had just read through it and I had skipped the date row when I did.  It works perfectly so far in my tests and the code is much simpler than what I had managed to mangle together.  This is great, thank you!